# Can someone explain what possible datatype this mean?

Tags: type-conversion

Can someone explain what possible datatype this refers to?

```
void (*sa_handler)(int)
```

from signal's man page.

Comment: It's a pointer to a function that takes an int and returns void.

Answer (score 0):

It is a signal handler function in UNIX.

You declare it and then pass it to [sigaction()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) system call.

Here untested code to catch `USR1` signal which you can send to you process with [kill](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1.html) command:

```
void my_function(int signal) {
    continue_looping = 0;
}

volatile int continue_looping = 1;

int main(void) {
    struct sigaction sa;
    sigset_t mask;

    sa.sa_handler = &my_function;
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESETHAND;
    sigfillset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL);

    while(continue_looping) {
        printf("Hello world\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You should be careful when calling any further functions from your action handler. I usually just set a flag there - as in the above example.